# Empty ListView doesn't appearance style

Tags: java, javafx-2

In case the ListView is empty it dosen't show the style, etc:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewExample extends Application {
      @Override
      public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        list.setItems(items);
        Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().add(list);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
      }
}
```

[image]

but if add one item the style show up:

```
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("First item");
```

[image]

Is there built in option (without adding empty item) for example:
[image]

Comment: What style are you talking about? `ListCell` or the `ListView` (background) ? What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I meant to ListCell, etc the different background of odd/even cells

Comment: let me see your styles, and if you can give me demo to recreate it, so the solution will also come with demo. but your solution in general is your listview is empty hence there is nothing to decorate, assuming your sytles do not tackle empty cells

Comment: @Elltz I upload images for example and full code